# Battery corrosion cleaned off with baking soda but car won't start now. Does the terminal need replacing?

Tags: battery, corrosion

I've got a 2014 Honda Accord V6. The positive batter terminal has been corroded for several months now. I first noticed it in January but never got around to removing the corrosion until today. I removed the battery and cleaned everything off with baking soda, but now the car won't start. It seems like the battery terminal has corroded too thin to make any contact.

[image]

Comment: Also when trying to tighten the nut, it torques the entire terminal upwards. So I can't tighten that terminal at all.

Comment: If it's loose, as a temporary fix you can cut up a soda can to shim the terminal until you can replace it.

Comment: Lightly scraping both the inside of the clamp and the terminal itself will probably get you good connectivity. You want to have fresh metal showing. If you are still loose, do as @Ben says for the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove that terminal and fit a new one - new terminals are available at most auto spares shops.

Do make sure that you get the correct one (positive terminals are larger than negative ones) -  the symbol just to the bottom left of the battery post does seem to show negative but as you say it is positive - just make sure...

Comment: Red is pretty indicative of a positive terminal. Also, doesn't the Honda battery terminals incorporate some kind of fusible link in them? While I agree with you this should be replaced, it may be a little tougher than going down to the parts store to find one.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 maybe maybe, but what is the symbol molded into the battery surface to the bottom left of the battery post...

Comment: I don't think it is a symbol. It looks like the cell cap. @paulster2 Honda puts the fusible link in the underhood fuse box

Comment: Well, only an image of the complete top of the battery will confirm exactly what is what...

Comment: Besides, the positive corrodes green, while the negative corrodes white. Thanks for the heads upon the fusible link, @Ben.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 copper corrodes green .... does depend if the fluid causing the corrosion is coming from the battery or is just moisture under the bonnet...

Comment: I have petroleum jelly on battery terminals to minimise corrosion problems...

Comment: [Here, please use this as a reference.](https://goo.gl/images/B57XsA)

Comment: Again depends on where the fluid causing the corrosion comes from...

Comment: Thanks for all your advice. It is indeed the positive terminal, it leaked out a lot of green stuff before cleaning it up. The annoying part was I had to get a jump start to start the car and couldn't stop the engine or I wasn't able to start it again. So I took it to the shop on the same day to get the terminals replaced. Probably got overcharged, but didn't have a choice.

Comment: What's confusing to me is after the car jump starts, how does all the electronics work if the battery has a poor enough connection that it can't even start the car?

Comment: Because small loads like ignition and lights have a small current demand which only causes a small voltage loss due to the resistance - when several hundred amps are required the connection fails.